# PoH Reordering Attack

Tags: solana

In the Solana white paper, the author mentions how to generate the sequence timestamps when events come into the picture. Their proposal appends the previous hash to the input to compute the next hash.

While it certainly prevents the reordering attack in section 4.5, I don't see how it prevents an attacker from using the last legit hash prior to inputting reversed events. Using the notation from the paper, the attacker uses the true prior hash, hash10a, instead of hash10b. Now the attacker submits event3+hash10a, computes hash20c, and publishes to peers. How can a peer know whether either hash20c or hash20a is legit?

Answer (score 0):

When you said attacker, does that mean PoH generator(Leader) right?
Because in the section 4.5, I think they determine to prevent malicious PoH generator not a malicious client node.

For your case(if you mean PoH generator)
since the client node hash their data transaction with the last observe hash that means if PoH generator alter client transaction the hash that it produced wouldn't be the same as what client had hashed(since data changed = hash changed). The client then compared hash and stated that PoH generator had changed the result.

But what does not state in the white paper is how client states that since client is not always validator node.